# Label text won't update

Tags: c++, api, winapi, label

#### About

I have a simple app with tabcontrols, buttons and a progressbar.
Now I want a simple label/text above the progressbar which says something like "Waiting ..", "Progress (0%)" etc.

#### Issue

The Label does not update.

#### Wanted

A simple solution to update a label. (similar to .NET).

```
'Like this
Label1.Text = "Doing stuff .."
```

#### Attempts

1

```
GetDlgItem( HWND_LABEL_STATUS, INDEX_LABEL_STATUS );
SetWindowText( HWND_LABEL_STATUS, "Doing stuff .." );
```

2

```
SendMessage( HWND_LABEL_STATUS, WM_SETTEXT, INDEX_LABEL_STATUS , reinterpret_cast< LPARAM >( LPCTSTR( "Doing stuff .." ) ) );
```

3

```
HWND label = GetDlgItem( HWND_LABEL_STATUS, INDEX_LABEL_STATUS  );
label->SetWindowText( "Doing stuff .." );
```

4

```
SetWindowText( HWND_LABEL_STATUS, "Doing stuff .." );
// and/or
SetDlgItemText( HWND_LABEL_STATUS, INDEX_LABEL_STATUS, "Doing stuff .." );
RedrawWindow( HWND_LABEL_STATUS, nullptr, nullptr, RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
```

Comment: This question needs more context. How is the data processing (for which progress bar is displayed) being done, in regards to attempt to set new status? If it is being done without pumping message loop, during the processing, your attempts at sending the message to the control, won't execute, until your processing ends, and messages are pumped from the message loop. Side note: your attempts 1-3 are all equivalent = does exactly the same thing, since `SetWindowText` translates to `SendMessage` with `WM_SETTEXT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your label is a child of a dialog, and the label has a dialog item ID assigned to it, you can use this:

```
SetDlgItemText(hwndMyDialog, ID_LABEL_STATUS, TEXT("Doing stuff .."));
```

Or this:

```
HWND label = ...; //label = GetDlgItem(hwndMyDialog, ID_LABEL_STATUS);

SetWindowText(label, TEXT("Doing stuff .."));
//or
//SendMessage(label, WM_SETTEXT, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(TEXT("Doing stuff ..")));
```

Either way, if the label text is not updating on-screen correctly, then chances are you are probably doing something to block the calling thread's message loop from processing new paint messages (such as updating the label in a loop that is doing something else).  At the very least, you can use `UpdateWindow()` to process pending paints:

```
UpdateWindow(hwndMyDialog);
```

```
UpdateWindow(label);
```